# laravel route:any page expired to inactivity

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using in laravel 5.5 a route for Any:

```
Route::any('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('homepage');
```

The route should be a GET one, but because of a third provider which redirect with a POST i had to change it to any;

The problem is when redirect is made from the third party (with post) now i get:

```
The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.
```

this is because of the {{ csrf_field() }}

How can i pass the csrf_field and make that route act as a GET one even if i get a POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note**: Do not disable CSRF protection unless you know what you are doing.  I only suggest this because it appears they are not actually POSTing any data to the application on this route.

You can exclude URIs from CSRF protection by adding the URI to the $except array in the VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

```
protected $except = [
    '/',
];
```

Comment: they can change the redirect from POST to GET but.....for security reason i don't want to display in url: ? get params. Is there a better solution? should i remove all the get params from request then return clean url?

Comment: What are the parameters being used for?  Are they modifying anything in your application?

Comment: there are not modifying anything....that't why i want to ignore the post.

Comment: If the parameters aren't being used to modify anything, then you can use the above method.  There's no reason for CSRF protection if they can't modify anything by posting to the route.

Comment: in except array can we use route('name') instead of '/' ?

Comment: No, you can't use a function in the property definition.

Answer (score 0):

Just add csrf() inside your forms tag.